# TextField inside UICollectionViewCell go crazy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
Cell *aCell = [collectiveView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

return aCell; 
}
```

I have a collectionview and one textfield inside each cell

I discover that some unexpected behavior
sometime the text in the textfield disappear or duplicated to textfield in other cell randomly

How can I fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using reusable cells (from `-dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`), the cell you get back *may have the contents of a previous cell in it already*. You need to explicitly clear the contents of the text field in the cell you get back before you return it. For example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" 
                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textField.text = @"Default contents"; // or other data from your model
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's possible. However, it's not recommended, as evidenced in the [UICollectionViewCell docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html): "You typically do not create instances of this class yourself... When you want a new instance of your cell class, call the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method of the collection view object to retrieve one."